# Javascript Open() does not work using Smarty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I have a module in WHMCS which has a client side button which, when pressed needs to open a new page using javascript.
I am not sure what would be blocking it, but when I add the {$download} value to the template it shows the correct link to be opened, and I cannot find errors in the console, but nothing happens.

I have a else statement which does run when the button is not clicked, and does not echo when i do click it, so the press is detected, the new windows just does not open, kind of like it is being ignored.

Anybody have an idea of what might be causing this?

```
{if $download != '-1'}
    {literal}
        <script type="text/javascript">        
            window.onload = function(){
                var win = window.open('{/literal}{$download}{literal}', '_blank');
                if(win){
                    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
                    win.focus();
                }else{
                    //Broswer has blocked it
                    alert('Please allow popups to download this file.');
                }
            }
        </script>
    {/literal}
{else}
    {$download}
{/if}
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the reason the code was ignoring the function. It seems the `window.onload = function(){}` was causing the issue, removing the `onload` clause removed the error.

Comment: check your browser console for error.

Comment: @urfusion I did there is nothing there like i mentioned above.

Comment: what is the value of `{/literal}{$download}{literal}`

Comment: @urfusion `{$download}` is the link that needs to be opened.

Comment: try with passing static url something like `http://google.com`

Comment: @urfusion same result. It does nothing, it is like the javascript is not executed at all

Comment: @Marcel You show the code before it is complied but what is the actual source code that is generated? Also try put in `console.log()` throughout the JS then you can see how far it gets